# Remove numeric prefix from string - PHP regex

Tags: php, regex

Would somebody care to help me out with a regex to reliably recognize and remove any number, followed by a dot, in the beginning of a string? So that

```
1. Introduction
```

becomes

```
Introduction
```

and

```
1290394958595. Appendix A
```

becomes

```
Appendix A
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
preg_replace('/^[0-9]+\. +/', '', $string);
```

Which gives:

```
php > print_r(preg_replace('/^[0-9]+\. +/', '', '1231241. dfg'));
dfg
```

Comment: Note that `.` represents one arbitrary character and not the period character.

Comment: Two things wrong with this one that aren't a problem in @Romain's answer: `[0-9]*` will match zero digits, which is bad - use a `+` instead of the `*`, and the `.` is a special character which means "match any character", and should be escaped by preceding it with a backslash (`\`).

Comment: How's this different from?

/[0-9]+\./g

Besides being greedy and verbose?

Comment: @mplacona It starts with a ^. Very important.

Answer (score 9):

I know the question is closed, just my two cents:

```
preg_replace("/^[0-9\\.\\s]+/", "", "1234. Appendix A");
```

Would work best, in my opinion, mainly because It will also handle cases such as

```
1.2 This is a level-two heading
```

Comment: @Felix cheers, this is very good and a case I hadn't though of myself. +1.

Comment: If you consider this answer to be better than the currently accepted one, you can switch it. I'm not trying to steal anyone's thunder, I'm just thinking about anyone with the same problem ending up on this page and not seeing the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Voilà:

```
^[0-9]+\.
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this does not qualify for *recognize and remove any number, followed by a dot*, but it will return the desired string, e.g. Appendix A, so it might qualify as an alternative.

```
// remove everything before first space
echo trim(strstr('1290394958595. Appendix A', ' '));

// remove all numbers and dot and space from the left side of string
echo ltrim('1290394958595. Appendix A', '0123456789. ');
```

Just disregard it, it it's not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Stuff after string

```
$string = "1290394958595. Appendix A";
$first_space_position = strpos(" ", $string);
$stuff_after_space = substr($string, $first_space_position);
```

Stuff after dot

```
$string = "1290394958595. Appendix A";
$first_dot_position = strpos(".", $string);
$stuff_after_dot = substr($string, $first_dot_position);
```

Comment: forgot the closing parenthesis, so I closed them for you.

Comment: cheers, but those will both eat everything (e.g. `A. Appendix A`), not just numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
/[0-9]+\./
```

Btw, I'd definitely use a **regular expression** here as they are very reliable and lightweight.

Cheers

Comment: Actually, any sentence like this one would get corrupted !1.

Comment: Corrupted? What do you mean? It would not

Comment: There is no *g* modifier in PCRE.

Comment: Fair enough, but it sure is better than the marked solution. Removed the /g

Comment: No, it is not. As pointed out earlier, "123. Chapter 3. The one with the spaghetti" would become " Chapter The one with the spaghetti", which is not the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
print preg_replace('%^(\d+\. )%', '', '1290394958595. Appendix A');
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP function to search a string for a regular expression and to replace that with something else is [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). In this case you want something like:

```
$mytitle = preg_replace('/^[0-9]+\. */', '', $myline);
```

Comment: It should be `preg_replace('/^[0-9]+\. */', '', $myline)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str="1290394958595. Appendix A";
$s = explode(" ",$str,2);
if( $s[0] + 0 == $s[0]){
  print $s[1];
}
```