# Result of a find() query as an array of rows in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

**What I'm trying to do:**

Obtaining the result of a find() query in Cakephp as an array of rows

**Why?:**

I want to send the results to Excel, so the regular cakePHP format does not suits me.

**Solutions I know of:**

I see two possible solutions:

- custom SQL query
- treating the returned array to fit my needs

**My question:**

Is there a simpler solution to get the solution in a standart format: an array with rows?

**Edit:**

cakephp returns arrays like this:

```
$data=array("0"=>array("ModelName"=>array(Model.field1,Model.field2),
                       "LinkedModelName"=>array(LinkedModel.field1,LinkedModel.field2)

)
```

I want:

```
$data=array("0"=>array(Model.field1,Model.field2,LinkedModel.field1,LinkedModel.field2));
```

**Solution: (thks Dave):**

```
    foreach($data as &$row){
    $row = Set::flatten($row);
    }
```

Comment: cake *does* return results as an array of rows. Post an example of the output you require

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the book [[here]](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html), you can use `Set::flatten($data);` to "Collapse a multi-dimensional array into a single dimension".

It's example:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    array(
        'Post' => array('id' => '1', 'title' => 'First Post'),
        'Author' => array('id' => '1', 'user' => 'Kyle'),
    ),
    array(
        'Post' => array('id' => '2', 'title' => 'Second Post'),
        'Author' => array('id' => '3', 'user' => 'Crystal'),
    ),
);
$res = Set::flatten($arr);
/* $res now looks like:
    Array (
        [0.Post.id] => 1
        [0.Post.title] => First Post
        [0.Author.id] => 1
        [0.Author.user] => Kyle
        [1.Post.id] => 2
        [1.Post.title] => Second Post
        [1.Author.id] => 3
        [1.Author.user] => Crystal
    )
*/
```

From there (if you need), it should be pretty simple to remove the `#.` prefix on the fields.

Something like this possibly:

```
preg_replace('/^[0-9]+\.+/', '', $string);
```

I haven't tested it, but it's an accepted answer to a very similar issue here: [Remove numeric prefix from string - PHP regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398316/remove-numeric-prefix-from-string-php-regex).

Comment: Nice. Now I just have to flatten each row. Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad to help.  It helped me learn too - I wasn't aware this existed until your question made me search for it, so... thanks :)  +1'd your question.

Comment: FYI, as of 2.2 Set:: has been deprecated in favor of hash:: [http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html]

Answer (score -1):

Define the following method in your App Controller file:

```
//flattens a multi-dimensional array (recursive implode)
function r_implode( $glue, $pieces )
{
    foreach( $pieces as $r_pieces )
    {
        if( is_array( $r_pieces ) )
        {
            $retVal[] = r_implode( $glue, $r_pieces );
        }
        else    
        {
            $retVal[] = $r_pieces;
        }
    }
    return implode( $glue, $retVal );
}
```

And simply call it into your code:

```
 $data = $this->r_implode(',', $data);
 pr($data);
```

As you were asked you need to implode inner arrays like:

```
$data=array("0"=>array(Model.field1,Model.field2,LinkedModel.field1,LinkedModel.field2));
```

Then you can do it using foreach loop:

```
foreach($data as $key => $indexed_array)
{
     $data[$key] = $this->r_implode(",", $indexed_array);
}
pr($data);
```

Comment: You can also use `array_map() method with the callback to implode method`. Ref Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259947/php-implode-multidimensional-array-to-tab-dilimited-lines

Comment: I think this falls under the "treating the returned array to fit my needs" that the OP already suggested and was looking for an alternate way.

Comment: Of course.  I also read the **_actual question_**:  "Is there a simpler solution to get the solution in a standard format: an array with rows?"  "Simpler" meaning simpler than the examples he gave.  All you did was answer with a complicated loop - something he apparently already knew how to do.